# How i can use in href, customer edit url?

Tags: magento2, customer

If i try this:

```
<a href="http://shopname/admin/customer/index/edit/id/1/"></a>
```

it'll return to the dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

The admin uses some secret keys in the URL generated based on the URL and a random string that depends on the session in order to avoid CSRF attacks.

But you can generate the url to the customer edit page in a block or template on the admin side like this:

```
$url = $this->getUrl('customer/index/edit', ['id' => 1]);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works in template and block, but in controller no. How i can do it in controller? I tried $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('customer/index/edit', ['id' => 1]); but return a bad url